# Svelte 3 - How to loop each block X amount of times

Tags: javascript, arrays, svelte, svelte-3

I'm hoping to find a way to iterate over an #each block a set amount of times in Svelte 3. In Vue I would do something like this:

```
<li v-for="i in 3"><!-- somecontent --></li>
```

But as I understand Svelte handles loops much differently using the .length property of the array being #eached. Is there some way to pull off something like this in Svelte?

```
{#each 3 as i}
  <li><!-- somecontent --></li>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 163, accepted):

An `#each` tag can loop anything with a length property, so:

```
{#each {length: 3} as _, i}
    <li>{i + 1}</li>
{/each}
```

will also work, if you prefer.

Comment: This answer better suits my needs because for a long iteration it is better not to create a looooong array I think.

Comment: Agreed, much better solution IMHO too

Comment: Docs: https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each "You can use each blocks to iterate over any array or array-like value — that is, any object with a length property."

Comment: An array with length = 10000 is just an object with { length: 10000 } and a few extra methods. There is, afaik, no substantial overhead between writing Array(10000) and { length: 10000 }

Answer (score 125):

You can use `{#each ...}`, like:

```
{#each Array(3) as _, i}
    <li>{i + 1}</li>
{/each}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this #each block re-render anytime the number variable changes (from 3 to 5 for example?). I'd like to render a certain number of form items based on previous user input. Ex: How many cars do you have? --> Number of Text Inputs created for each Car Make/Model, for example.

Comment: @Doomd: yes, see an example: https://svelte.dev/repl/fef2db8c70064c49913a6608ebf633b9?version=3.18.2

Comment: If you're going to do that - please key it @doomd so that Svelte can keep track of additions/removals:

{#each x as _, i (x.id)}

or similar.

Answer (score 2):

i Use like this for travelling from `a` to `b` in Svelte

```
{#each Array.from(Array(b+1).keys()).slice(a) as i }
    <h1>{i}</h1>                    
{/each}
```

example (1 to 100):

```
{#each Array.from(Array(100+1).keys()).slice(1) as i }
    <h1>{i}</h1>                    
{/each}
```

Comment: Very cool, not as useful for 1-X since you can use one of the other simpler approaches for that. But this has some interesting possibilities for pagination https://svelte.dev/repl/509ac9d542644544a282966aef6879e1?version=3.44.3

Answer (score 1):

You can use clean variable from the script section (mmm... for a pagination):

```
// script
export let numOfPages = 10
const pagesArray = Array.from({length: numOfPages}, (x, i) => i+1) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

// template
{#each pagesArray as page}
    <li>{page}</li>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with helper:

```
/* code */
export function range(from, to) {
    const result = [];
    let i = from;

    while (i <= to) {
        result.push(i);
        i += 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

```
<!-- template -->
{#each range(1, 3) as i}
    <li><!-- --></li>
{/each}
```