# How to render a component multiple times based on integer in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

Case: Render the Button component 5 times

```
<script>
  const timesToBeRendered = 5;
</script>

<Button/> //Render this component x (5) times
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213585/svelte-3-how-to-loop-each-block-x-amount-of-times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [svelte `each`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-blocks)

```
<script>
  import Button from './Button.svelte'
  const timesToBeRendered = 5;
</script>

{#each Array(timesToBeRendered) as _, index}
  <Button key={index} />
{/each}
```

[Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/b1bd2c6c485b4f29ac5d845f3797b9ba?version=3.29.7)

Answer (score 0):

`new Array(timesToBeRendered).fill(0)` will create an empty array with N 0's, that you can loop over. (yes the fill is required)

`new Array(timesToBeRendered).fill(0).map((_, i)=><Button key={i}/>)` will return a list of components, which react renders as siblings.

Dont forget `key` otherwise react cannot distinguish between the elements!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this was a Svelte specific question

Comment: The first part of the answer is valid for svelte but it's better to show a code example using svelte each